# Flutter changenotifier not updating or recalling the paint function after loading the images?

Tags: image, flutter, paint

I have the following function. The problem here is that I need to load all this 3 img and recall the paint function. I am trying to use ChangeNotifier after I get the image but it seems not working or refreshing the ui/rebuild? What else can I change to get it refresh only after all 3 images loaded completely.

```
        class BarChartPainter extends AxisChartPainter<BarChartData>
            with ChangeNotifier {
          late Paint _barPaint, _bgTouchTooltipPaint;
        
          List<_GroupBarsPosition>? _groupBarsPosition;
        
         BarChartPainter() : super() {
    _barPaint = Paint()..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

   
    asyncFunction().then((val) {
      print("Return after build and await" + val.toString());
      notifyListeners();
    });

        
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your async code to use `async/await`.

```dart
 var _data1 = await rootBundle.load('assets/img/pic1.png');
  _img1 = await decodeImageFromList(_data1.buffer.asUint8List());
  
  var _data2 = await rootBundle.load('assets/img/pic2.png');
  _img2 = await decodeImageFromList(_data2.buffer.asUint8List());

  var _data3 = await rootBundle.load('assets/img/pic3.png');
  _img3 = await decodeImageFromList(_data3.buffer.asUint8List());
  
  notifyListeners();
```

So the refresh operation (`notifyListeners()`) runs only when the others have completed.

Comment: I have still the same issue cause I did some extra thing my function was the constructor so I build a separate function to do the await and build of the image then I call the notifyListener still the same. I have update my question above with my changes and your answer too

Comment: Could you explain what you're actually trying to achieve? Like for instance where is this painter used? Also include extra code so it's clearer.

Comment: actually I am trying to paint some column like bar chart and put this images on its right or left axis and I updated my question with the paint function too

Comment: Okay. Can you post the code for the widget where you're using this painter?

I think you need to get the images in the widget and then pass them down to the painter.

Comment: I have updated my question with the painter function ready. Yes you are right I am now trying to figure out on how to get the image and only then can it call the painter function

Comment: I am trying to do that but still stuck on it how to do any working idea I tried few things it failed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231218/discussion-between-victor-eronmosele-and-newbie).

Comment: I have tried like this too  asyncFunction().then((val) {
      _barPaint = Paint()..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

      _bgTouchTooltipPaint = Paint()
        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
        ..color = Colors.white;
      notifyListeners();
    });